# Custom mapping when mapping to new or existing entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm already successfully using `AutoMapper` in my ASP.NET Core application. I'm creating mapping configurations and mostly use `ForMember`, `BeforeMap` or `AfterMap` to customize certain mappings.

Now I have a particular scenario in which I import data and I update an existing entity if it exists or create a new if it doesn't. I would like to also use `AutoMapper` to map entities.

For example (kept simple) I have an import class:

```
public class ImportModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual model class:

```
public class ActualModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

As I parse and iterate through the import rows I currently do:

```
var model = modelService.Get(x => x.Number == item.Number);
if (model != null)
{
    model.Description = item.Description ;
}
else
{
    model = new ActualModel() {
        Number = item.Number,
        Description = item.Description 
    };
}
```

Now, basically I would like to change the above into (hopefully) a single line using a mapping configuration to add/update a model.

Is it possible to achieve this (maybe using additional `AutoMapper` features customer resolvers, construcstors, etc)?

Comment: Use the `Map` overload that takes a destination object. If you pass `null`, a new one is created for you.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Ah ok I didn't known about that overload. So basically I'm configuring the map using `MemberList.Source` and I would assume that only the source properties will be mapped without overwriting unknown destination members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload

```
destination = mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source, destination);
```

does the trick.